# Preloading Cache Express

Tags: reactjs, express, caching, preload

I'm working on a back-end / API built with Express for a dashboard built with Next/React.
Each distinct API call requires data to be fetched from an Elasticsearch cluster. All endpoints accept a date-range parameter. Requests are cached using `node-cache`, but if a request is made with a new date-range, it requires a new Elasticsearch Query which takes time. I know that for any given hour all requests can at most ask for 5 different predefined date-ranges [date-ranges go until the end of the current hour].

I'm interested in preloading data to the cache at the beginning of every hour so that when an API call is made with predefined parameters the data will already be in the cache.

How can I do this?

Comment: Set a recurring timer that fires at the beginning of every hour.  When that timer fires, make a database call to the newest available query(s) so it will get cached.  Since you show NO code at all, we can't help more specifically by offering you actual code snipppets.   We can generally help a lot more accurately and quickly and more specifically if you show the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Do you mean on the front-end?

Comment: I assumed the caching was on your server (on behalf of all users) so you would run the timer and query on your server to get it into the server cache.

Comment: Yes, it is done on the server. I don't have any idea how to do that. Does this require calling API endpoints from within?

Comment: Show us the relevant query code on the server please.